# tweepy error in user_timeline

Tags: python, tweepy

So I'm trying to get a timeline of a specific user. Here is the code:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'numbers'
consumer_secret = 'numbers'
access_token = 'numbers'
access_token_secret = 'numbers'

user_list = [list of users]
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for user in user_list:
    for page in api.user_timeline(screen_name =user, count = 200):
        print page
```

I've tried using the old documentation. When I run it I get the "Sorry, that page doesn't exist. Code 34"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer reading through the code documentation change screen_name to user_name

```
for user in users:
    for page in api.user_timeline(user_id =user, count = 200):
        print page
```